# Тире перед "не"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире перед "не" в данном случае:
"**Иван не Иван, если не сделает этого**"?

Answer (score 2):

**Иван не Иван, если не сделает этого.**

Думаю, это вопрос о постановке тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, когда оба главных члена выражены существительными в именительном падеже. Грамота.ру указывает, что тире не ставится если

> перед сказуемым, которое выражено существительным, числительным или фразеологическим оборотом, стоит отрицательная частица НЕ, например: Старость не радость (посл.). ([Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172)).

Тире не стоит и в названии фильма "[Я не я](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%8F)".

Answer (score 2):

**Иван не ИвАн, если не сделает этого.** Нет паузы и тире.

Согласно основному правилу, тире при наличии частицы НЕ между подлежащим и сказуемым в форме И.п. обычно не ставится, однако **может быть поставлено при наличии паузы.**

Выбор варианта может быть авторским, но с учетом структуры предложения и расстановки логических ударений. Довольно часто тире можно встретить в **распространенных** предложениях.

Это правило применимо **и в случае повтора слова**, что можно видеть на примере сочетания ***жизнь не жизнь*** по материалам Нацкорпуса.

Примеры:

1) Нет тире при простом повторе и отсутствии паузы

Теперь мне это непонятно, теперь думаю что без тебя **жизнь не жИзнь**, а грусть и скука. [Н. М. Карамзин. Бедная Лиза (1792)]

Сашенька смотрела в потолочное окошко, слегка заметенное пылью, и невольно думала о том, что хорошо бы, конечно, эту пыль смахнуть, да лень лезть на крышу, однако мама права ― надо «чистить-блистить», без этого **жизнь не жизнь и человек не человек.** [Вацлав Михальский. Весна в Карфагене (2001)]

2) Тире ставится в распространенных конструкциях или при наличии паузы.

Пойманная и зафиксированная в ограниченном пространстве **жизнь ― не жизнь, а лишь форма существования белковых тел.** [Татьяна Соломатина. Большая собака, или «Эклектичная живописная вавилонская повесть о зарытом» (2009)]

Избавление если и приходило, то лишь в момент прикосновения к бумаге, где **жизнь ― не жизнь**, где нет границ,  а чувства, плещущего через край, нет смысла стыдиться. [Петр Алешковский. Седьмой чемоданчик (1997-1998)]